# How can i make my first form with a selected field prepopulate that field in a second form in Django

Tags: django

I'm new to Django, started learning it this week. I have made my models.py like so:

```
class EmployeeTrack(models.Model):
time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=False)
eid = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name = 'Employee')
tmp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='temperature')
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural='Employee Tracking'

class Employee(models.Model):
first_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
last_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
email= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

My question now is how can I make two forms. First form , with one input field like for example id, and then enter a employee id, Pass that id via a redirect or something to the second form for the model EmployeeTrack which has all it's fields listed but also populated the employee eid field based on my previous input in the first form so i can add a EmplyoeeTrack entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to modify the EmployeeTrack model according to the ID to which it belongs, for that I would make some small modifications in your model first:

```
class EmployeeTrack(models.Model):
    tmp = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, verbose_name='temperature')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    EmployeeTrack = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeTrack, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()

    # in this way at the moment of instantiating the object you will have its data in string
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

after that we create the forms of the models:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import (
    Employee,
    EmployeeTrack
)
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
        )

class EmployeeTrackForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeTrack
        fields = (
            'employee','tmp',
        )
# what we do is add an inline formset to the form
EmployeeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Employee, EmployeeTrack, form=EmployeeTrackForm,
    fields=['tmp', ], extra=1, can_delete=True
)
```

and in your administrator it would be even simpler:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import (
    Employee,
    EmployeeTrack,
)
class EmployeeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Employee,
    extra = 1

@admin.register(EmployeeTrack)
class EmployeeCustom(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    inlines = [EmployeeInline]
```

and with that you would have the structure

Comment: This is super helpful, but it seems i didn't structure my question right. What I need is not editing but adding a new EmployeeTrack entry via a form which contains all the fields from the model including a foreign key to the Employee table. I want 2 forms. First one would just submit the data and send it to the next form, via a redirect or something. The first form would just pass the data for the employee id. Then the second form would appear which would have all it's field listed, and just the employee field would be populated based on the passed employee id which would be identical.

Comment: You still don't structure your question well, what you want is that from the Employee model you can add data in your Employee Track model?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanations.I want to add just the EmployeeTrack entry to the database via a form. Employees are added to the db via django admin so that is covered. I imagined that in the frontend there would be one input field for the Employee id. I would want then to add a EmployeeTrack record for that Employee without manually having to select from the list of Employees. I would't be adding Employees at all via a form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!